Fluent-Bit - How to extract part of a file name and append it to log_stream_name for Cloudwatch log group
New to Fluent-Bit and looking for some guidance on this.
Latest version of Fluent-Bit is installed on ec2 and successfully running and working. I am pushing logs from /var/log/nginx... to Cloudwatch
Example, I have logs in /var/log/nginx/client.test-access.log
I want to use Fluent-Bit to extract the 'client.test' and append it to the log_stream_name so that it appears in the Cloudwatch log stream as client.test
I have been trying to use rewrite_tag
[INPUT]
Name tail
Path /var/log/nginx/*access.log
Tag nginx.access
Path_Key filepath

[FILTER]
Name rewrite_tag
Match nginx.access
# Example assumes log file name is e.g. *.test.com-access.log
# with a destination log group of /aws/ec2/access-logs
Rule $filepath ^/var/log/nginx/(.*)-access.log$ nginx.access.$1
Emitter_Name re_emitted

[OUTPUT]
Name                cloudwatch_logs
Match               nginx.access.*
region              eu-west-2
log_group_name      /aws/ec2/access-logs
log_stream_name     fluent-bit-${TAG[2]}
auto_create_group   true

But it is showing blank in the cloudwatch log stream, can anyone advise if I am doing this correct or is there a better way?
P.S If this isnt possible is there a way to for fluent-bit to simply append the server name to the log_stream_name in cloudwatch logs?
